# I have "00001" ID format in mysql, how to implement it to JTable?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I have generated all information from the table in mysql to my jtable, the ID format is "00001" but in my jtable it displays "1" only. Anybody knows how to generate the same format from mysql to jtable?

Comment: *the ID format is "00001"* The field in MySQL have no any format. What do you tell about? Maybe you mean ZEROFILL attribute of a numeric field?

Comment: i have used zerofill to achieve "00001" on mysql ID column and i want also to do this to my jtable but it displays only "1" on my jtable ID Column.

Comment: Despite the presence of ZEROFILL, the data type of the field remains numeric. And so it is displayed as a number, without leading zeros. Use the appropriate formatting on the client side. `String.format("%05d", ID)`.